# Html column group and title

Tags: html, css

What would be the html markup to achieve the same result as the first table in http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/tableformatting#tableformatting__tbl_table-objects-display-values

I am looking for how they specified the column group and how to set the title (Women, Men). Also, how to target the specific column group in css.

thanks,
bsr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. I sat down and reflected on the last time I addressed table formatting issues, then navigated to following links:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4
- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html

After some meditation and drinking water, wrote some code for you to refer:

```css
body {
  background: #e4e4e4; 
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
th {
  background: #d5d6d6;
}
td {
  background: #fff;
}
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 1em 0.5em;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 4px;
}
tfoot {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <thead>
    <tr><th rowspan="2">Question</th><th colspan="2">Women</th><th colspan="2">Men</th></tr>
    <tr><th>Yes</th><th>No</th><th>Yes</th><th>No</th></tr>
   </thead>   
   <tbody>
    <tr><th>Question1</th><td>42%</td><td>58%</td><td>61%</td><td>39%</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Question2</th><td>53%</td><td>47%</td><td>69%</td><td>31%</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Question3</th><td>26%</td><td>74%</td><td>51%</td><td>49%</td></tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
    <tr><th>Average</th><td>40%</td><td>60%</td><td>60%</td><td>40%</td></tr>
   </tfoot>
</table>
```

Mostly when I try to see such layouts, I attempt to count how many rows and how many columns will be necessary in the final html. This helps to construct the html properly.

CSS then simply becomes a selection of those elements with either classes or elements. For your question I chose elements.

HTH!

@gsvolt

Answer (score 0):

I just write the same table as you mentioned in a link. I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
thead th,
tbody tr td:first-child {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Question</th>
        <th colspan="2">Women</th>
        <th colspan="2">Men</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Yes</th>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Yes</th>
        <th>No</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Question 1</td>
        <td>42%</td>
        <td>58%</td>
        <td>61%</td>
        <td>39%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Question 2</td>
        <td>53%</td>
        <td>47%</td>
        <td>69%</td>
        <td>31%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Question 3</td>
        <td>26%</td>
        <td>74%</td>
        <td>51%</td>
        <td>49%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Average</td>
        <td>40%</td>
        <td>60%</td>
        <td>60%</td>
        <td>40%</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

To make a `<th>` span a set of rows, give it a `rowspan` attribute. For collumns, a `colspan` attribute.

To then target that `<th>` element, use the normal CSS selector methods, such as `.class`, `#id`, `tag`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `<colgroup>` and `<col class="men">`

see: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/08/13/top-10-css-table-designs/ 
5. Vertical Zebra Style